# Subclassing NSDictionary not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary that I read from a plist. I want to create a subclass of `NSDictionary` to implement something like the following, so that I can avoid using `@"key name"` everywhere in my source code:

```
@interface MyDict{
}
-(NSString*) textString;
@end

@implementation MyDict
-(NSString*) textString {
    return [self objectForKey:@"textString"];
}
@end
```

In my other method:

```
MyDict *d = ... // something i read from plist
NSString *str = [d textString];
```

When I call the method, the app crashes because of "unrecognized selector textString". What is wrong here?

Comment: Is this your exact code? Is your @interface actually that? OR is it @interface MyDict:NSDictionary {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has no superclass. Also, the conventional wisdom is that it's very difficult to subclass `NSDictionary` because it is an [class cluster](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FGeneral%2FConceptual%2FDevPedia-CocoaCore%2FClassCluster.html&ei=B93RTc7ZEKrjiALul4XNCg&usg=AFQjCNEgAvwUwvMY2qE-2DiK2A_72EPoEA). You don't actually get an `NSDictionary` back when you:

```
NSDictionary * myDict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

You get a private subclass (`NSCFDictionary` in this case).

You might want to try defining your own dictionary keys, the way Apple does:

```
NSString * const MyWonderfulUnicornKey = @"MyWonderfulUnicornKey";
```

Comment: It's simpler and maybe safer to use, I guess, global variable. My desire is just to avoid typo and increase maintainability. However, how can I use a common header file to declare this? I have many files using it. But if I just import a common .H, the compiler would complain re-declaration, even when I embed it in  #ifndef XXXX #endif block

Comment: Put the import and the `#ifndef` into your project's .pch That's what it's there for, as I understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Just assigning an NSDictionary to a MyDict pointer doesn't make it a MyDict instance.

One way you can do this would be to create a category to add your method to NSDictionary. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1 for info.

Comment: +1 subclassing `NSDictionary` is a bad idea, but a category would be more appropriate way to do this.

Comment: BTW--NSDictionary may not be an actual instance of an NSDictionary class--it's funny like that. Add a category to NSDictionary instead.

Comment: A category really **is not** an appropriately solution. You'll be adding that generic method to every dictionary instance in the app.  Almost assuredly, there is a better design pattern to employ.